# How to parse dictionary inside alamofire model?

Tags: swift, dictionary, alamofire

I have some struct which equals response model. But I have one field which I can't parse correctly. It was shown below:

```
"qualification": {
        "12201": 2,
        "11924": 1,
        "1335": 1,
        "1339": 1,
        "471": 4
    }
```

so as you can see it is simple dictionary. But such type isn't acceptable in Alamofire:

```
Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because '[String : Any]?' does not conform to 'Decodable'
```

The problem is that I don't receive fields via name, I have only some id and equal value for it.And this is only one field which has such problems. All another model fields are good and has fields for parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have managed to solve this problem via:

```
var qualification:[String:Int]?
```

and as I see Alamofire accepts such dictionary. Maybe it will help someone else :)